# QNEAT3 doesn't work on all networks

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, routing, network, distance-matrix

I have a point layer and three different network layers and am trying to create OD-Matrices for all the points using the QNEAT3 plugin.

It did work out fine on two of the three networks, but the third always returns just NULL for all the relations. 
The networks that work are buslinenetworks, one taken from a local bus companies opendata service, the other one I created myself. The third represents the streets of the city. The data is taken from OpenStreetMap.

When I simply try routing between two points, it works out fine and returns the entry, network and exit costs for the relation. Only when using the algorithms to create a martrix I get empty results for all the relations.

Did anyone ever have a similar problem or might know where to find the problem?

Comment: This error is due to low data quality (almost 99 of 100 times) . Did you try to set a higher tolerance value? Be sure to install the latest version of QNEAT3 because there has been a bug fixed regarding the tolerances in the latest version.

Comment: I've tried different tolerance values between 1 and 100000000 but I always got the same result.